# AHK find and fill form fields without com

Tags: jquery, forms, autohotkey

My voip provider has changed to a "modern" web interface (with jquery harmonica) to set some telefoon settings. What i want is just 2 settings. Setting one: Home: Forward all business calls to my home telephone

Setting two:  Business:  "Leave all calls at my business expect when it isn't answer.

I already had a system in Auto hot key.

```
Send {TAB}
Send %phone number%
Send {TAB}
Send %forward number %
Send {TAB}
etc.
```

But now options are just with a mouse click on an icon. It harmonica (jquery) out and then you can fill the fields.

My quistion is: 
1) Is there a way To find a certain text in a webpage and mouseclick on it 
2) Is there a way in AHK to fill a form field (not using COM)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** It might be possible if you know where on the screen the options are, then issue a `MouseClick, whichbutton, x,y` command (see also [link](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm))

You can locate the x,y location if you use window spy (accessed by right clicking the autohotkey icon in the system tray and selecting the windowspy, then click into the application of your choice to get windowspy to populate with values)

This option is of course requires that you havn't scrolled or the webpage hasn't changed.

---

**Option 2**
Use the `send` command to feed in a predetermined number of `{tab}` keys till it reaches the field in question then issue a `send` with `{up}`, `{down}`, or `{space}` to select

This is of course limited to what the UI will allow you to do. The trick here is to see if you can first do it manually with a keyboard, then just use the `send` command to force those keystrokes.

---

**Option 3** Use a COM object. I resisted doing this too... for longer than I should. After finally learning how to do this, I kicked myself for resisting.

Of course this will only work with Internet Explorer (yuck). But it's awesome because via a COM interface you can select fields that are off screen without needed to scroll to find them.

More information can be found about interfacing with IE via COM at [[LINK]](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64563-basic-ahk-v11-com-tutorial-for-webpages/) which is where I learned how it's done. They have some pretty sweet examples.